# How do I implement a Python function to find distances of all pixels from a given point along a binary mask image

Tags: python, image-processing, graph-theory, path-finding, mathematical-morphology

Assume I have a binary image (simply represented as a 2D numpy array), with some of the pixels '1' where the mask is on and the other pixels are '0'. For example:

[image: 5x5 binary mask image]

I want to find the distances from the left-bottom pixel (index [4, 0]) to all the other '1' pixels in the mask image, **but the path may only travel along the mask pixels** (i.e. can't cross a '0' pixel). See the origin pixel below, marked in red:

[image: The task: find distances from the pixel marked in red]

In short, I want to get the following image:

[image: Desired output image]

In which all the mask pixels are marked with their L1 minimal distance from the seed pixel. I'm planning to apply the proposed solution on images around 100x200 pixels in size.

Is there a python function (or series of functions) that implement this?

I could of course convert the image to (sparse) graph and apply shortest path algorithm. Not sure how efficient that will be.

Comment: that... *is* an algorithm on a graph. [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) is one of the best known algorithms for path finding on grids. you don't have a general graph so that's going to help you. this is not really image processing however. a distance transform might work, or not. -- one simple algorithm would behave like floodfill, labeling pixels in the front with increasing distance.

Comment: Look up the [Fast Marching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_marching_method). This is the most efficient method I know of to do this. There are simpler methods, some will produce reasonable results, but will likely not be as precise.

Comment: Also, this is called a geodesic distance transform, if you search that term you should find existing implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using https://github.com/Forget-It-Not/Geodesic_Distance_Transform. It supports both L1 and L2 distances. The only caveat was that I had to pad the original image with one row (and column) of zeros from each side for the output to make sense.